# How to add '&onlyLock=true' in authorization URL of auth0-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0

I need to add a parameter  '&onlyLock=true' in the in authorization URL. However, I could not find information about this property in the current documentation.

¡is it possible??

I am using
auth0-js": "9.8.2".

Configuration:

```
new Auth0.WebAuth(
{ domain: config.domain,
  clientID: config.clientId, 
  redirectUri: config.redirect,
  responseType: "id_token token", 
  scope: "openid profile email"
 }
);
```

Execution

```
auth0.popup.authorize({}, (err, authResult)
```

Thanks

Comment: so.. you want to add another value to the query string of the URL?

Comment: @Richard Barker Yes,  exactly.

Comment: Just add it to the end of the url. Query strings are `&` delimited key value pairs. It's standard HTTP so I wouldn't expect Auth0 to have much about it. But there's plenty of info on that standard else where.

Comment: @RichardBarker Thanks for your answer. Yes, I could add it to the end of the URL with a custom logic. How ever, If I develop my custom logic to complete the authentication transaction, I will lose some features given by Auth0-js. So I need a solution no out of the box.

 I’m thinking. Is ‘&onlyLock’ a valid parameter of Auth0? or is it custom?